# Jquery mobile is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

My site works well in MS Edge, but chrome shows a grey dot in the middle of the screen. What causes the chrome error?

This is my index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/xy.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
<p align="center">Test</p>
    </div>

<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Kategorie suchen"  data-inset="true" data-count-theme="b">
    <li><a href="assets/beck/index.html" data-rel"dialog" rel ="external">Bäckereien </a></li>

</ul>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

> The script is linked correctly. xy.css is jquery from theme roller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your file on sever, it will work just fine there on all browser. Chrome has some compatibility issue with jQuery mobile library while running locally,  I am having same problem.

Comment: Issue fixed when i put my html and css on the server, but after i compile it in cordova for moible app, in some devices the issue exists, What you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

I use AptanaStudio3 and added a Google Chrome local server. my JQ Mobile code runs well on that local server